# median survival in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I can't calculate life table in R, in particular median survival:

```
library(survival)
kaplan17 <- read.csv(kaplan1, sep=";", dec=",")
head(kaplan17)
#       group time event
# 1     2     1     0
# 2     1     1     0
# 3     1     1     0
# 4     2     1     0
# 5     2     1     0
# 6     1     1     0

(my.surv <- Surv(kaplan17$time))
 # [1] 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
 # [48] 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

How can I correctly calculate the median survival per group?

My dataset can be downloaded [here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/uljejh)

Comment: Please do not use links to provide your data use e.g. `dput()` instead.

Comment: `Surv` only creates a survival object, you'll need `survfit` to perform a Kaplan-Meier. This apart, you cannot build a survival object with only a time variable, you need to use the status variable as well. I suggest you read some documentation about methods for survival data and at least `?Surv` and `?survfit`

Comment: I need get parameters of life table
if do that
(my.surv <- survfit(kaplan17$time))
I get error
Error in UseMethod("survfit", formula) : 
  no applicable method for 'survfit' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Comment: All the times were 1???? no data at link? Low quality question.

Answer (score 1):

```
?Surv
?survfit
survfit( Surv(time, event) ~ 1, data=kaplan17)
```

then

```
survfit( Surv(time, event) ~ group, data=kaplan17)
```